# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing when parsing a txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a txt file with a bunch of MD5 hash passwords (for an assignment)
my code is

```
with open('weak.txt') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        weak.append(eval(line.strip()))
        if 'str' in line:
            break
```

but I am a getting

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF,   File "<string>", line 1
    1660fe5c81c4ce64a2611494c439e1ba
                                   ^
```

I tried to add raw input to my code , but it just hangs. any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` on MD5 codes? `eval` expects its argument to be a string containing Python statements.

Comment: because all of the MD5 passwords are strings that I am just trying to get from the txt file. Am I completely off track ?

Comment: Yes, you are completely off trackline.

Comment: yes. try just removing `eval` and see where that gets you

Comment: What you get from the text file are already strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be calling `eval`.

```
with open('weak.txt') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        weak.append(line.strip())
        if 'str' in line:
            break
```

The `eval` function tries to interpret the string as a series of python statements. You don't want that . There is generally not a good reason to use `eval`. You want the md5sum as a string. When you iterate over `f` with the statement `for line in f`, you are asking the file object to return string objects to you for each line in the file. In other words, `line` already contains what you want, you don't need to ask the python interpreter to execute it.

Comment: ...especially on any type of input, be it from a file, user input, arguments, or a downloaded web page

Comment: @mhlester, true, though that is usually when `eval` (if ever) would be used: when you don't have the original source and need to run code dynamically. Otherwise, just run it with the rest of your code.

Comment: @PaulDraper Your statement makes zero sense. "You don't have the the original source and need to run code dynamically". How would using `eval` solve the problem of not having the source code?

Comment: @EricUrban, I could be more clear. The code must not be in the PYTHONPATH; it's in database or coming from some other input. `eval` is what you do when you didn't have the source code (in your PYTHONPATH) originally, but you acquired somehow during the course of your program.

Comment: @ericurban note `eval` will execute compiled code objects as well as text-based source code.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Absolutely. Hopefully people don't make it a habit of storing source code or bytecode in databases however.

Comment: A recent use case I had was for allow admins to dynamically add pieces of functionality using Python code. e.g. `lambda x: x == 1 or x == 2`. The input was trusted, but it was dynamic.